How to determine that an order has expired? The query order interface (/v2/checkout/orders/{id}) does not return the expiration time
Goal: Re-create an order by judging that the order has expired
Current situation: The order details query interface does not return the expiration time.
interface: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get
Expectation: How to tell when an order has expired.
level:high

The default order valid periods are

3 hours after creation (for approval to happen)
3 hours after approval (for capture or authorization to happen)
indefinite (after a successful capture or authorization that returns a payment object)

If capture/authorization was not successful, the order is not retained indefinitely.

Why can I still make payment after 6 hours in sandbox environment?
